# What is an entire question down voted called?

Tags: discussion, terminology

I don't know if there is a problem but I found this [question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128770/witcher-2-wont-start) IS there something wrong with it? They are all -1 voted.

Comment: It's colloquially known as der Whollequestionundanswerendownvotenspammung, why are you asking?

Comment: @badp I thought you were Italian not German.

Comment: @badp In the south it's just *ein Allesschlecht*.

Comment: @Resorath He lives in Germany right now. :P

Answer (score 5):

There's no term we have for this.

As for why it happened? It could be because everyone sees all of the provided solutions as subpar towards solving it - remember that the intent of downvotes is to mark answers that are not useful towards solving the problem, or questions that are not useful or unclear. We all have our own interpretations of what is or is not useful, and it's not black and white at all - that's why voting exists as a system and why it works. What some might just pass as meh, others might feel is bad advice and should be avoided. The newest answer is also just a poor answer because it suggests a solution that is already noted as attempted by the asker.